# sharing a list for an external user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, external-users

I have a requirement where we have to give access to an external user to a site which has a list with infopath form associated with it.

Is it possible to give access to an external user to a site with a list or even better send him a link to the infopath form where he can login and fill in and close the form.

Answer (score 1):

If enabled in the tenant, you can share SharePoint objects to external users.  They will be required to set up a Microsoft Account before logging in.  There are some caveats though:

- User must click the link within a time frame
- User can use any email they like once they have the link.  They do not have to use the email it was sent to.

To enable sharing on the tenant level:

1. From the SharePoint admin center, click **sharing**.
2. Select an option that starts with **Allow...** (or select **Don't allow...* to disable sharing).
3. Click **OK** to save the settings.

See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85#__turn_external_sharing) link for more information (including directions on how to enable per site collection instead of tenant-wide).

[This](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232) link has directions for sharing sites and documents to external users.  The directions for sharing sites mostly apply to libraries and list as well.

Comment: how much time do we have before the link expires ?

Comment: I don't remember, but I think they need to accept within a day.  We disabled external sharing on our tenant, otherwise I'd test.

Answer (score -1):

It's better to give access of your site/list to external users/vendors. This can be achieved using Forms based authentication where each external user would be assigned a username and a password to login. Windows/In domain users need not to login in the application. (There is a wsp available in codeplex for FBA which will allow you to maintain external users credentials from site settings and not from SQL server - https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/)

Please let me know if you need detailed steps to configure forms-based authentication by extending your existing web application.

Comment: I am using sharepoint online where you can share a site to an external outlook or microsoft live account. Once the user logged in he will be able to see the site and add his record in the list. Will this be possible ?

Comment: This is not valid in SPO